# Como pasar una función de un archivo js a otro

Tags: javascript, html, css, importación

Tengo dos archivos **javascript** y me gustaria **importar y exportar** funciones entre ellos, ya que tengo estados de pantalla que me gustaria guardarlos en este.

Estas son las funciones que me gustaria exportar a mi `main.js`. ¿Sería algo de esto para importarlo?

```
// import state from "./state"; ?

function showMenuDegustacion() {
  display.buttonDegustacion = true;
  cartaContainer[0].style.display = "none";
  okelaCookMenu[0].style.display = "none";
  menuDegustacion[0].style.display = "flex";
  postresVinosShow[0].style.display = "none";
  menuDiario[0].style.display = "none";
  menuAnimation();
  menuSelectedButton();
}
function showPostresVinos() {
  display.buttonVinos = true;
  cartaContainer[0].style.display = "none";
  okelaCookMenu[0].style.display = "none";
  menuDegustacion[0].style.display = "none";
  postresVinosShow[0].style.display = "flex";
  menuDiario[0].style.display = "none";
  menuAnimation();
  menuSelectedButton();
```

Comment: en principio no sería necesaria realizar la importación, lo que debes hacer es en el momento de cargar los archivos js, cargarlos secuencialmente, primero cargas el archivo dónde están esas funciones y luego cargas el main.js

Answer (score 0):

Con el comando **export** puede hacer uso de las constantes que quieras, pero en tu caso es un poco peligroso ya que tienes otras dependencias dentro de la función, si quieres tener estas funciones disponibles siempre solo debes llamar simplemente el archivo en tu html, si planeas exportar solo una constante en especifico usas **export**

```
export const showMenuDegustacion=()=>{
    display.buttonDegustacion = true;
    cartaContainer[0].style.display = "none";
    okelaCookMenu[0].style.display = "none";
    menuDegustacion[0].style.display = "flex";
    postresVinosShow[0].style.display = "none";
    menuDiario[0].style.display = "none";
    menuAnimation();
    menuSelectedButton();
}
```